# Is there any way to prevent multiple the same API calls in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

For example: I have 10 pages. And for 8 of them, I need to have the same data. So in the `getStaticProps` method I doing API calls. But they are the same! I don't want to do the same calls 8 times to get the same data. I want to do one call and have access to this data from anywhere.

Are we have some solutions for this?

Comment: you can create a system cache and if there is a data in your cache you can prevent api call , and you can set expire time for your cache to update after x minutes

Comment: @MohsenMahoski how can i set the system cache? can you share the link for a resource where I can check for this?

Comment: you can use packages like [memory-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-cache) or [node-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cache)  or even better implementation with [redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis)

Comment: you can read this article: [How to cache data in Next.js globally across all pages at build time](https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-cache-data-globally/)

Comment: @MohsenMahoski thank you so much! You helped me! You can add an answer below and I will set as correct answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can share data across all pages in build time by implementing a simple file system cache, when you get data from your api you can saving it in a file with specific name as key , for next time you can first check if there is a file with that key and get the data from it.